# SharePoint Online list and library item

Tags: sharepoint-online

Whenever an item is created in list with an attachment, the attachment should be uploaded  in a library. How can I achieve this in SharePoint Online.

Comment: Use power automate flow which will trigger on item creation/update, capture the attachment file content & create a new file in library using "Create file" action.

Answer (score 1):

As Ganesh mentioned in the comments, this can be done using Power Automate. This is the general structure of the flow.

[image: Flow structure]

Here are the first two actions expanded. The `ID` in the **Get attachments** action comes from the dynamic content of the **When an item is created** trigger.

[image: First two actions]

List items can have multiple attachments, so we need to loop over the response that comes back from the **Get attachments** action. Here is the **Apply to each** action expanded.

The `Body` in the **Apply to each** action comes from the dynamic data of the **Get attachments** action, as does the `Id` that's used for the **File identifier**. The `ID` that's used for the item Id comes from the **When an item is created** trigger.

In the **Create file** action, the `DisplayName` comes from the dynamic data of the **Get attachments** action and the the `Body` comes from the dynamic data of the **Get attachment content** action.

[image: Apply to each]

Comment: +1, very well explained answer @Rob.

Comment: Thankyou @Rob and Ganesh for your suggestion but I am trying do it through spfx and graph api

Comment: SPFx won't help you in this area. If you wanted to do this using custom code you would need to build a web service and then register a webhook with SharePoint or Microsoft Graph that would call the web service each time an item was added to the list. That said, you'd be doing a lot of extra work to achieve the same thing that you could build in Power Automate in less than 30 minutes.